# Creating/resizing arrays...can't use non-constant?

Tags: c++

I have a struct defined as

```
struct Point {
int x, int y
}
```

I am getting an array of Points passed into a function, as well as an integer i that tells me how many elements the array contains. How in the world can I just add an element into the array? I realize there is no method to just add new elements, as arrays can't be dynamically resized, so I need to create a new one and copy each element over...but when I try to do the following:

```
Point newPoints[i+1];
```

I am told that it expects a constant value, which of course I can't give it since I need i+1, and i is variable. C++ makes me sad. (If it isn't obvious, I come from a land where some divine being manages all your objects for you...)

P.S. I *must* use arrays...forgot to mention that.

Comment: Why must you use arrays?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232445/dynamic-arrays)

Comment: C++ has a std::vector designed just for this!

Answer (score 2):

In standard C++, you cannot create an array with a run-time-set size.  You will need to do one of:

1. Declare `newPoints` as a pointer and then allocate the value using `new Point[i+1]`, applying `delete []` to it later.
2. Declare `newPoints` using something like `boost::scoped_array`, which manages cleanup automatically.
3. Use a non-array, such as an `std::vector`; you can use `&v[0]` to get a pointer from that.
4. Use a non-standard extension, such as the one provided by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Answer (score 0):

Afraid you're going to have to use a new/malloc on this one. i is only determined at runtime, so there's no way it can statically allocate the memory it needs on the stack at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you must use a constant value is that the `newPoints` array is being created on the stack, and to do that the compiler must know how big it is going to be at compile time. To be able to specify a dynamic size you must use either new[] and delete[], or a dynamic data structure class (like from the STL).